# Wordpress Elementor

Tags: wordpress

I changed the color of the site title with css and made it white in the elementor page editor. But when I open my website in a separate tab, the site title color is black. How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: So you gave your site title a separate class in elementor?  You also cleaned the cache?

Comment: I installed the Wp Fastest Cache plugin, cleared the cache. The problem is not fixed. I gave color to the site title in the customize appearance section, by writing css code in the additional css section.

Answer (score 1):

Few things you have to check.

1. Clear the Cache of browser and website(if website have any cache active)
2. Check the color of the title style. It should be global color.

Comment: .site-title a {color: white;}  I wrote this in the additional css part. Isn't it global? I cleared the website's cache with the Wp Fastest Cache plugin. Chrome I cleared your cache.

Comment: it should be global. then you can inspect the site-title that from where the css color is coming. if the .site-title a is correct, you can try .site-title a{color: white !important;}

Comment: !important; Adding it fixed it. Thank you so much :) . I was struggling for 3-4 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "!important" to your rule.
Sometimes your style is not important and WordPress uses style from another place.
Here is an example:
`.body { background-color: coral!important; }`

Btw this is not a good practice, but it is an easy and fast solution!